# vb. Changing Registry Value with Vb Program

Tags: vb.net, registry

This is what the registry entry looks like:

`A1="OS Ver";A2="Patch Ver";A3="Location Number"`...

My script will take location number for instance 'A3' value and pass it onto a VB program I am trying to write. The VB program reads the input, determines if A3 exists and changes the value.

Here's a snippet of the VB code:

Module Main
Public Sub Set_A3(declare String)
Open Registry
GetValue
If A3 exists change A3="Location number" to input
Registry.Close
End Sub

Sub Main()
Declare line as String
Readline
If line contains input call function
End Sub

Where I am getting stuck is from a command like the program works fine. However as soon as I incorporate it within the script, it hangs reading all other entries.

Question, how do I call the readline function when program comes up on the special character from script before getting the location number and then stop?

Any other ways to approach the whole thing??!!

I hope I did an OK job describing the issue. If any question, please ask. Truly appreciate the help.

Code per Ken White's request:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Module Main
Public Sub Set_A3(ByVal A3 As String)
        Try
            If A3 <> "" Then
                Dim sConfig As String
                Dim regKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\SS\Location\Variables", True)
                sConfig = regKey.GetValue("VariableGroups")
                Dim sConfigNew As String = ""
                Dim s() As String = sConfig.Split(";")
                For i As Integer = 0 To s.Count - 1
                    If s(i).Contains("A3") Then
                        s(i) = String.Format("A3={1}{0}{1}", AU, Chr(34))
                    End If
                    If s(i).Contains("A4") Then
                        s(i) = String.Format("A4={1}{0}{1}", "New Configuration", Chr(44))
                    End If
                Next
                Dim bFirst As Boolean = True
                For Each stmp As String In s
                    If bFirst Then
                        sConfigNew = stmp
                        bFirst = False
                    Else
                        sConfigNew = String.Format("{0};{1}", sConfigNew, stmp)
                    End If
                Next
                regKey.SetValue("VariableGroups", sConfigNew)
                regKey.Close()
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("No Location Number Input")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("RegSet Error: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim line As String
            line = Console.ReadLine()
            If line IsNot Nothing And line.Contains("-a3") Then
                Set_A3(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2).ToString())
                line = Console.ReadLine()
                If line.Contains("True") Then
                Exit
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

So what happens after the program coded above gets called, is readline going through all other input before getting to '-a3' and thus it will just sit there. Whereas, if I just call the .exe file via cmd with this parameter '-a3 12345' it will populate the A3 field just fine in registry.

Hope this helps. Please help. I really appreciate any suggestion/inputs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your actual code. It's very hard to debug pseudocode; as it won't run in any case, it's hard to say why it "from a command like the program works fine" (???) while when you "incorporate it within the script, it hangs" (???), because neither of those makes any sense whatsoever. Questions about code you've written need to contain the actual code, and a clear description of the problem you're having; this question in its current state contains neither.

Comment: Ken, thank you very much for the welcome and clarification. Here's the code. Please bear with me as I am learning the nuts or bolts of posting. I have always been a lurker, this is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

This should do roughly what you need. It was hard for me to understand based on your pseudocode. You will have to mod it a little for what you need. My guess is you'll want to replace newStr with your "input".

```
    Dim str As String
    Dim reg As RegistryKey
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim posEnd As Integer
    Dim strFinal As String
    Dim strLook As String = "A3="""

    Dim newStr As String = "Replaced With This"

    reg = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("software\test", True)
    str = reg.GetValue("test")

    If str <> String.Empty Then
        pos = str.IndexOf(strLook, 0)
        If pos <> 0 Then
            posEnd = str.IndexOf("""", pos + strLook.Length + 1)
            strFinal = str.Substring(0, pos + strLook.Length) & newStr & str.Substring(posEnd, str.Length - posEnd)
            reg.SetValue("test", strFinal)
            reg.Close()
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Please don't answer poor questions like this one before they're edited. You've removed all incentive to edit it, and now encouraged future poor quality questions by this poster (and potentially others). Thanks.